# Updating model value inside component doesn't reflect inside ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to dynamically create a new tab using jqxTabs, i am trying to update the model when new object is added to the array that updation doesn't update the view.

**View** : In the view below i have attached the event handler addTab. Inside that method i am updating the model but it isn't getting updated in the other ngFor.

```
<jqxTabs #tabsReference [width]='"90%"' [height]='200' [position]='"top"'
     [animationType]='"none"' [selectionTracker]='false'>

    <ul>
     <li style="margin-left: 30px;" *ngFor="let item of data;" (click)="addTab(item)">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
     </li>
 </ul>

 <div *ngFor="let item1 of data">{{item1.desc}}</div>

</jqxTabs>
```

**Component** :

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { jqxTabsComponent } from '../../bower_components/jqwidgets/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxtabs';
import { jqxCheckBoxComponent } from '../../bower_components/jqwidgets/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxcheckbox';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
data = [{
    name: "slide1",
    desc: "Node.js."
  }, {
    name: "slide2",
    desc: "JavaServer "
  }, {
    name: "slide3",
    desc: "Node.js ."
  }, {
    name: "add slide +"
  }];

  addTab(item) {
    var ss = item.name;
      if (ss == "add slide +") {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
          if (i == this.data.length - 1) {
            this.data[i].name = "new slide";
            console.log(this.data);
          }
        }
      }
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      ( < HTMLElement > document.getElementById('animation').firstElementChild).style.marginTop = '10px';
      ( < HTMLElement > document.getElementById('contentAnimation').firstElementChild).style.marginTop = '10px';
    }
}
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong. Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: You are updating only the `name` property, but the second `ngFor` only shows the `desc` property which you are not changing at all

Comment: Also your for loop is unnecessary since you are only updating the last array entry. This could be easily done without a for loop with `this.data[this.data.length-1].name = "new slide"`